# OpenOffice Calc - Highlighting the higest value in a column

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

So I've got this spreadsheet open using OpenOffice Calc (ver 3.3.0) and its set up a little like this:

```
 A           B          C         D
1.name     quantity     price     total
2.foo      10           10        100
3.bar      20           6         120
4.red      30           7         210
```

Each cell in the "total" column is obtained by multiplying the two cells to the left of it, and what I'm trying to do is to get it so that Calc highlights the highest value in the total column (even better if it could highlight the entire row). I've tried using MAX(D1:D4) in the Conditional Formatting section, but it highlights multiple values. How do I get it to highlight just the highest value?

Answer (score 6):

You should use `MAX($D$1:$D$4)` instead, in your condition.

To highlight the whole row, you can select `Formula is` instead of `Cell value is`, and use the following formula: `$D4=MAX($D$2:$D$4)` (assuming you selected your block starting from A1 and ending in D4):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to test whether a value is MAX
Highlight A1:D4
[image]

```
=IF($D2=MAX($D$1:$D$4),1,0)
```

This highlights the row, make sure to use the $D2 not D2 or $D$2 so the formula adjusts correctly for the range